# Wordpress url error on form actions on unix web server (~...)

Tags: wordpress, url, .htaccess, url-rewriting, admin

I have an error with my wordpress installation... I explain myself:
My wordpress is now on an unix based server with directadmin to manage my domains...
I have configured a new domain on witch I can access by: http://ipaddress/~username...
Then, for my personal needs, I access to this website through another domain name using an htaccess redirection like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://ipaddress/~username/$1 [P,L]
```

Here, just all work fine. The problem is in admin panel, on the forms actions (for exemple when I save the general configuration, or when I select many posts by checking, selecting the "move to trash" action and clicking on "Apply"...
Wordpress execute the action and try to display this url:

http://subdomain.example.com**/~username**/wp-admin/edit.php?trashed=1&ids=456

Why wordpress add /~username in the url?

Answer (score 0):

H have solved the problem with an htaccess file. Here is the code within :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ~[^/]*/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R]
```

That just redirect without the /~username and make all works fine

Thanks to Will :)

Olivier